# Access images inside public folder in laravel

Tags: laravel

How can I access the images stored inside `public/images` folder without the use of Laravel's own functions like `assets()`?

I just want to get the direct URL of the images stored in images folder.

Eg:

```
localhost/webapp/images/stackoverflow.png
```

When requesting the link i should get the direct image.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

If you are inside a blade template

`{{ URL::to('/') }}/images/stackoverflow.png`

Answer (score 52):

Just put your Images in Public Directory (public/...folder or direct images).
Public directory is by default rendered by laravel application.
Let's suppose I stored images in `public/images/myimage.jpg`.
Then in your HTML view, page like: (image.blade.php)

```
<img src="{{url('/images/myimage.jpg')}}" alt="Image"/>
```

Comment: In my case images are in storage/app/uploads folder, this gives <img src="http://localhost:8000/uploads/1630736422_e.png" alt="Image"> but image is not showing.

Comment: https://pbphpsolutions.com/2021/05/how-to-display-image-from-storage-app-public-folder-in-laravel-8.html this solved my issue

Answer (score 22):

I have created an Asset helper of my own.

First I defined the asset types and path in `app/config/assets.php`:

```
return array(

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Assets paths
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Location of all application assets, relative to the public folder,
    | may be used together with absolute paths or with URLs.
    |
    */

    'images' => '/storage/images',
    'css' => '/assets/css',
    'img' => '/assets/img',
    'js' => '/assets/js'
);
```

Then the actual `Asset` class:

```
class Asset
{
    private static function getUrl($type, $file)
    {
        return URL::to(Config::get('assets.' . $type) . '/' . $file);
    }

    public static function css($file)
    {
        return self::getUrl('css', $file);
    }

    public static function img($file)
    {
        return self::getUrl('img', $file);
    }

    public static function js($file)
    {
        return self::getUrl('js', $file);
    }

}
```

So in my view I can do this to show an image:

```
{{ HTML::image(Asset::img('logo.png'), "My logo")) }}
```

Or like this to implement a Java script:

```
{{ HTML::script(Asset::js('my_script.js')) }}
```

Comment: Very nice approach. Have implemented, thx!

Answer (score 15):

You simply need to use the `asset` helper function in Laravel. (The `url` helper can also be used in this manner)

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/arrow.gif') }}" />
```

For the absolute path, you use `public_path` instead.

```
<p>Absolute path: {{ public_path('images/arrow.gif') }}</p>
```

If you are providing the URL to a public image from a controller (backend) you can use `asset` as well, or `secure_asset` if you want HTTPS. eg:

```
$url = asset('images/arrow.gif'); # http://example.com/assets/images/arrow.gif
$secure_url = secure_asset('images/arrow.gif'); # https://example.com/assets/images/arrow.gif

return $secure_url;
```

Lastly, if you want to go directly to the image on a given route you can redirect to it:

```
return \Redirect::to($secure_url);
```

More [Laravel helper functions](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers) can be found here

Comment: If needed, you can use `secure_asset()` also in a blade file

Answer (score 12):

when you want to access images which are in public/images folder and if you want to access it without using laravel functions,
use as follows:

```
<img src={{url('/images/photo.type')}} width="" height="" alt=""/>
```

This works fine.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it worked perfectly

```
<img style="border-radius: 50%;height: 50px;width: 80px;"  src="<?php echo asset("storage/TeacherImages/{$teacher->profilePic}")?>">
```

this is used to display image from folder i hope this will help someone looking for this type of code

Answer (score 0):

Crete file .htaccess in root && add
...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.css|.js|.png|.jpg|.gif|robots.txt|.ttf)$ [NC]
...