# How to display image that is stored in public folder?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I use the below store function in my controller. And the image im uploading is getting stored in the public/images/ folder. How can i display that image in view? Pls help me.

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $this - > validate($request, [
        'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);

    $imageName = time().'.'.$request - > image - > getClientOriginalExtension();
    $request - > image - > move(public_path('images'), $imageName);

    $stock = Stock::create([
        'tag_no' => $request - > input('tag_no'),
        'image' => $imageName,
        'user_id' => Auth::user() - > id
    ]);

    if ($stock) {
        return redirect()->route('stocks.index', ['stocks' => $stock - > tag_no])->with('success', 'Stock created successfully');
    }
}
return back() - > withInput() - > with('errors', 'Error creating new Stock');
}
```

Comment: You might want to look at your example: there's a mismatch in the parenthesis. I've tabbed it more neatly so the issue is clearer.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26286175/access-images-inside-public-folder-in-laravel

Comment: Hey i figured it out Thanks :)

Comment: You'd normally store files in the `storage` directory under a path made by `storage_path('folder')`. In your case, `storage_path('public/images')` would be great. When you then use `php artisan storage:link`, a symlink is create for the publicly available path `/public` to the private path `/storage/public`. This also adds more security as the public path normally does not have write permissions.

Comment: <img src="/images/{{$stock->image}}" height="100" width="100">

Comment: ohhh thanks... so creating symlink is the more secure way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way to do in your view.

```
<img src="/images/{{$stock->image}}" height="100" width="100">
```

If you have stored image in a custom folder like:

```
 $request->image->move(public_path('/storage/'.Auth::user()->company.'/stock-images'), $imageName);
```

Here the folder is **/public/storage/companyname/stock-images/**

So to display use the below code:

```
<a href="/storage/{{Auth::user()->company}}/stock-images/{{$stock->image}}" target="__blank">
<img class="pull-right" src="/storage/{{Auth::user()->company}}/stock-images/{{$stock->image}}"  height="100" width="100"></a>
```