# After successful getting the result from filter how to show in blade file in Laravel 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-8

I am working on the filter part in search page but the issue is In the main search page all the result looped from the controller, and Now I am using jquery for the filter process, but things are confusing. How to do this in a right way?

So here is the process :

Step 1 : user search something Like "support" and then system go to the searchController file and give the result

```
return view('/search')->with(["documents" => $results, "filters" => $filters]);
```

Here $filter indicates the category filters; Like this
[image]

Then When User click on any category then it will filter the result but now the issue is I am using jquery and now things getting weird. Can somebody help me on this.

JS Code :

```html
$(document).on("click", ".category_filter1",function() {
    var test = new Array();
    $("input[name='category_filter']:checked").each(function() {
        test.push($(this).val());
    });
    showValue(test);
});

function showValue(data){
    $.ajax({
        'url': 'search/filter/'+(data.length > 0 ? data : "all"),
        'type': 'GET',
        success: function(response){ // What to do if we succeed
            if(response.data == "success")
                document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = response.categories;
        },
        error: function(response){
            // alert('Error');
        }
    });
}
```

and The Controller from where all result came from :

```html
public function filter($data){
        $t_data = explode(',' , $data);
        $filters = $this->load_filters();
        if(count($t_data)>0 && $t_data[0]!== "all"){
            $results = DB::table('documents')
                        ->whereIn('category', $t_data)
                        ->paginate(5);
        }else{
            $results = Document::paginate(5);
        }
        return redirect('/search')->with(["documents" => $results, "filters" => $filters]); // This part is really confusing
    }
```

So the flow will be like this :

[image]

Comment: ` now things getting weird` what do you mean by weird, also what you have shown in last diagram you want to redirect from controller but request is to be send by ajax?

Comment: I want to build a category filter as shown in the picture, But there are checkbox so I have to call function via ajax, If I call the function from ajax then I have to loop the result via jquey, So, How I will manage the previous result and replace those results with the filters result because the data is originally came from the seachController.  I know things are messy here

Comment: But I didn't get the whole process of doing this?

Comment: return the response from controller as json, then when you call the request for filter as per checkbox then show the result you got as json using jquery; as you told you want result as per checkbox , then once user clicks on checkbox send the jquery request to controller it will return a json then show the result by looping through json

Comment: But there is a catch in it, My images are loading vie **<img src="{{ route('load_image',$data->document_id) }}" class="img-fluid rounded" alt="">** then I will not hit the URL for image.

Comment: Can't I do this without jquery?

Comment: put the images in public folder then you will not even have to call the routes to show your images fast loading as it is

Comment: `Can't I do this without jquery?` then you will have to refresh the page complete, how are you planning to do it, if you don't want jquery then use vue or any other frontend frameworks

Comment: /storage/public or the main /public folder ? Current it is in the /storage/public folder

Comment: main public folder

Comment: ok thanks for the help, I think I have to go with this @bhucho

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38980278/9471283 this shows how to call a file from public folder images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing from as discussed in comments,

- In order to call the controller without refreshing the page you need to use ajax, (use jquery or any other frontend framework). Return your response as json,

```
return response()->json($your_return_array);
```

- For images store it in public folder, such as `public/images/your-image.png`.
  Then call it using url() method in your blade.

```
<img src="{{url('/images/your-image.png')}}" alt="Image"/>
```

Comment: nice representation of your question as well :)